# change focus between two views in split view

Tags: mac, keyboard, macos, split-view

Let's say that I have two apps running beside each other is splitview , How to change the focus from one to the other , e.g. if I am using two editors, If I am writing to editor 1, after the shortcut I will be writing in editor 2.
I know how to do it by the mouse but how to do it using only keyboard shortcuts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to post a different question to see if there's a way to write an applescript/keyboard maestro macro to hack this together using system properties (since I'm sure OS X is storing *somewhere* variables that encode which apps are splitting which space, what the current space is, and what the current focus is). But [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213767/93751) to the question [Switch focus in split view](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213766/switch-focus-in-split-view) makes it seem like there is no way to do this by default either across 2 different apps or within two instances of the same app.

In it they suggest using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> for moving between two instances of the same app, and the closest by default would be <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇥</kbd> for different apps.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by binding a keystroke to the "Move focus to active or next window" shortcut. It's under the "Keyboard" category on the "Shortcuts" tab of the Keyboard settings in System Preferences.

Comment: this works erratically (sometimes works, other times doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

I have Safari in [Split View](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948) and the keyboard shortcut of command + tilde (  ⌘ + ` ) works perfectly in 2023 on MacOS Venture (13.2).

This was mentioned in @mpacer's answer in 2015 but at that time it appeared like it wasn't a standard solution.