# Switch focus in split view

Tags: keyboard, terminal, macos, split-view

I know how I can have to apps open side by side in split view, but I have a slightly different case.

I have *two* terminal windows open side-by-side, is there anyway I can quickly switch between them. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a keyboard shortcut to switch between two splitscreen apps, but since they're both Terminal, if they're the only two Terminal windows you have open, you can use the Cycle Through Windows shortcut - <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>(the key that becomes ~ if you hold Shift).